# Qt get signal caller and read from a file line by line

Tags: c++, qt

I have two problems:
The first one is fairly simple - I have a list of buttons. I want when one of them is clicked to be removed from the list and then the dynamically alocated button to be deleted. This is the code of the **slot** I wrote (there is some extra info in the code):

```
    void Window :: bla2()
{
    //I fond somewhere on the internet that apperantly "sender()" should return a pointer to the caller;
    for(int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++)
    {
        if(List[i] == sender())
        {
            List.removeOne(sender());
        }
    }
    delete sender();

}
```

Alright, now for my second question I want to read a text file line by line and each line add as an element to a vector of  NOTE this is the .cpp file of a derived class that acts as a window so everything is already defined in the header part.

```
 vtext = new QFile("one.txt"); // QFile variable
    while (vtext->atEnd() == false)
    {
       line = vtext->readLine(); //QString
           quotes.push_back(line);//quote is QVector<QString>
    }
```

Comment: Do not ask more than one question in one post. You should make two separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question:

you are not allowed to delete an object in a slot called by that object in Qt. This is for good reason because you there may be other events posted to the object or other slots which will be called as a reaction to the current event which expect to find a valid object. Consider the situation were the button click signal is connected to multiple slots, if the first slot deletes the sender we are in undefined behavior land. Qt provides `deleteLater()` for for this situation. `deleteLater()` postpones deleting the object until the program enters its event loop again. It is also safe to call delete later multiple times.

Change your code from `delete Sender()` to `Sender()->deleteLater();`

If your list is of QWidgets rather than QObjects you need to cast the result of Sender() to a QWidget. If you are absolutly certain that this slot can only be called from something that is a QWidget you can just go ahead and use `static_cast<QWidget*>(Sender())` but I would highly recommend testing if the QObject is a QWidget first by calling `Sender()->isWidgetType()` which returns true if the sender is actually a Widget.

As far as your second question goes I it looks like it should do what you think, I can't see what the question is really. On StackOverflow it is good practice to ask one question at a time. I would suggest editing this question and taking out the second half and posting it as a new question. Its also good practice to give a short contained example that others can compile and test with.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This doesn't solve the problem though. I get a syntax error on the following line:
List.removeOne(sender());

With the following error message
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\Cutie\ToDo2\Window.cpp:21: error: C2664: 'QList<T>::removeOne' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QObject *' to 'QWidget *const &'
with
[
    T=QWidget *
]
Reason: cannot convert from 'QObject *' to 'QWidget *const '
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast